# Add Line Separator after results while using Grep Patterns

Tags: grep, rhel

I'm trying to separate my grep results out with empty lines but I can't figure out where to put or if I can even use group separator when -e is in use:

```
tail -100 testing.log | grep -e pattern1 -e pattern2 -e pattern3 -e pattern4 --group-separator=$'\n\n'
```

If I move group-separator after -e instead it'll complain that pattern2 is not a file/directory

```
tail -100 testing.log | grep -e pattern1 -e --group-separator=$'\n\n' pattern2 -e pattern3 -e pattern4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synopsis (as found in the manual) that you are looking to user for GNU `grep` is

```
grep [OPTIONS] -e PATTERN ... [FILE]
```

That is, if you have options to `grep`, these should come first, before any pattern expressions given with `-e`.  In your case:

```
grep --group-separator=$'\n\n' -e pattern1 -e pattern2 -e pattern3 -e pattern4
```

Note, though, that `--group-separator` does not come into effect unless you use GNU `grep` with `-A`, `-B` or `-C`.

Comment: This adds the separator after each pattern, is there a way to get it to add just after the last pattern? In this case just after pattern4?

Comment: @Z_ero No, you can not selectively use `--group-separator` for certain patterns.